# R masking a raster takes too long

Tags: r, geospatial, raster, r-raster

I am a novel R learner trying to carry my thesis.

I have a very large land cover Raster (all NYC with a 3x3 feet resolution).

To test my scripts, I wanted to use the mask function to extract a portion of the raster, for example, the Bronx, or a part of it.

For this, I have a shapefile with low level administrative areas, such as community districts or census tracts. after importing both of them, I can see how both layers are spatially overlapping (using bbox and plot). However, when I try to do the mask, it takes so long that I still have not seen any result.

When trying this on ArcMap, the same operation takes a very short time.

The operations carried out are:

```
#importing the different layers
land_cover <- raster(land_cover.img)
Bronx <- readOGR(filename)
#to make sure they have the same CRS, i change the projection of Bronx
Bronx <- spTransform(Bronx, crs(land_cover)
land_cover_bronx <- mask (land_cover, Bronx)
```

It is that last line that takes a very long time to process, and makes me suspect that something is not running well. Could there be any problem with the projections of each of the layers? [compareCRS returns TRUE, and the plot shows that they do verlap].

Comment: The `mask` function could be slow in R depends on the size of raster and several other factors. See the discussion from this blog to see if it helps: http://www.gis-blog.com/increasing-the-speed-of-raster-processing-with-r-part-13/

Comment: The post I shared is a series of three posts. The other two on the same blog may also provide some insights. In addition that, this post could be helpful: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130522/increasing-speed-of-crop-mask-extract-raster-by-many-polygons-in-r

Comment: Thank you very much! this helped me figure out it was a problem of memory, not of my own coding.

Comment: For the record - the problem of this raster was not its size. It seems like the raster had its piramids already built, and R was unable to process it. The file can be found in this link, if interested.
https://data.cityofnewyork.us/download/9auy-76zt/application%2Fzip